# How to Fix: failed to upload the package. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-packages, dart-packages

I am trying to publish my first package for the first time and when I use `flutter packages pub publish`, it give me in the end.

```
Uploading...
Failed to upload the package.
pub finished with exit code 1
```

The log for `flutter packages pub publish -v` is:

```
ERR : Failed to upload the package.
FINE: Exception type: ApplicationException
FINE: package:pub/src/utils.dart 512:5                                                      fail
    | package:pub/src/command/lish.dart 109:9                                               LishCommand._publish
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                            Future.catchError
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 113:52                                                     captureErrors.wrappedCallback
    | package:stack_trace                                                                   Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 126:11                                                     captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command.dart 164:13                                                   PubCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 196:27                                               CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 150:26                                            PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 138:18                                            PubCommandRunner.run
    | C:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\third_party\dart\third_party\pkg\pub\bin\pub.dart 9:48  main
[+15501 ms] "flutter pub" took 15,607ms.
[   +6 ms] pub finished with exit code 1
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _DefaultPub.interactively (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:366:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      PackagesPassthroughCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:267:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[   +6 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 4ms
[   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

I tried to delete `credentials.json` file and the auth process gave me success but it still the same problem.

Comment: I've tried many ways, still doesn't work ， my issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98386

Comment: How did you solve this problem @"Mahmoud Haj Ali"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68241172/13005736

Comment: I have same problem and it fixed after changing my ip.

Answer (score -2):

I found it.

1. delete `.pub-cache` folder inside `src/flutter` and invalid cach
2. invalid cache and restart your IDE
3. in terminal `flutter packages pub publish`

done.